# select vs multiple concurrent coroutines receiving on different channels : Is there a difference in logic or in performance?

Tags: go, select, concurrency

Select vs multiple concurrent coroutines receiving on different channels : Is there a difference in logic or in performance ?

My question is more generally about the implementation of an "fan-in" scheme in Go. It seems to me that the scheme using "select" does not work in the case of an arbitrarily large amount of channels (large array of channels).

See receive() and receive2() in the example hereunder.

Is the receive2() function overcomplicated? Overkill?

Why is the select formulation regarded as more idiomatic ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var ch1 = make(chan int)
    var ch2 = make(chan int)

    send(ch1, ch2)
    //receive(ch1, ch2)
    receive2(ch1, ch2)

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

}

func send(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan int) {
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch1 <- i
        }
        close(ch1)
    }()
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch2 <- i
        }
        close(ch2)
    }()
}

func receive(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan int) {
    go func() {
        for item := range ch1 {
            fmt.Printf("1: %d\n", item)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for item := range ch2 {
            fmt.Printf("2: %d\n", item)
        }
    }()
}

func receive2(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case x, ok := <-ch1:
            fmt.Println("ch1", x, ok)
            if !ok {
                ch1 = nil
            }
        case x, ok := <-ch2:
            fmt.Println("ch2", x, ok)
            if !ok {
                ch2 = nil
            }
        }

        if ch1 == nil && ch2 == nil {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about a scenario where the gooroutines do more than printing the values?

Comment: My question is more generally about the implementation of an "fan-in" scheme in Go. It seems to me that the scheme using "select" does not work in the case of an arbitrarily large amount of channels (large array of channels).

Comment: Yes, receive2 is limited to a predetermined number of channels.  The two approaches can be very different if the application maintains shared state when processing values from the two channels or if the application takes a long time to process a received value.

Comment: receive2 has the advantage of not having a lurking data race if you do something more complicated as printing. Abstract questions like this do not make much sense as you are comparing solutions to different problems.

Comment: [reflect.Select](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Select) can handle up to 64k channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is not a fan-in. The fan-in collects the results from multiple channels into **one** channel. Something like this, where you can receive all values on the single `out` channel.

```
func fanIn(in ...chan int) chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    for _, c := range in {
        go func(i chan int) {
            for v := range i {
                out <- v
            }

        }(c)
    }
    return out
}
```

In your implementation, the first `receive()` is simply receiving concurrently from N channels, independent of each other. It can be rewritten to accept a vararg and can *look* more like an actual fan-in:

```
func receive(cs ...chan int) {
    for i, cN := range cs {
        go func(i int, c chan int) {
            for item := range c {
                fmt.Printf("%d: %d\n", i, item)
            }
        }(i, cN)
    }
}
```

The `receive2()` instead is essentially sequential and won't scale, since you would have to write one `case` for each channel, and `&&` them all together to know when to break the loop. The `&&` may be rewritten with a `sync.WaitGroup` but you'll still process only one item at each iteration (at random, among the cases that are ready to receive).

Comment: No, receive2() (the solution using the select keyword is not sequential -that’s the whole point of « select »-). it is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @SergeHulne it is sequential, in that the values are processed one by one. Only **one** case will be selected at each iteration

Comment: All right, in that sense, indeed, it is.  :-)

Comment: So, basically it is like putting a mutex around each of the closures called from receive()